Can't create GeoPDF in QGIS (MacOS)
I am trying to create a GeoPDF in QGIS (Project > Import/Export > Export map to PDF). I'd like to tick the box "Create geospatial pdf" but it is greyed out. Please assist, an alternative way to create a geospatial document (for Avenza) with QGIS would also work.
The details:

upgraded from qgis 3.10 to 3.16 (my MacOS version doesn't support anything higher that 3.16 - but according to the web 3.16 should work)
GDAL complete 3.1 (I cannot install the GDAL extra plugins though (ECW, Grass, MrSid) because they require a higher version of MacOS
MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

I am beginner and might struggle with complex explanations.

Likely you do not have a coordinate reference system set in your map.  Go to the Project menu and choose Properties.  From the Project Properties dialog choose CRS.  Set a CRS that is appropriate for your data, area, and use.
If I have No CRS check (as shown below) my export to PDF options becomes grayed out.  If I have a CRS defined I can export to geospatial PDF.

